# How to compute the determinat of $\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G$ and $\mathcal F \oplus \mathcal G$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, determinant, vector-bundles

Let $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal G$ be vector bundles of rank $n$, $m$. Then how to compute $det(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G)$ and $det(\mathcal F \oplus \mathcal G)$?

I know the answer is $det(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G)=det(\mathcal F)^{\otimes m}\otimes det(\mathcal G)^{\otimes n}$ and $det(\mathcal F \oplus \mathcal G)=det(\mathcal F)\otimes det(\mathcal G)$. I remember them as matrixes, but I don't know how to prove them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For tensor product, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571839/determinant-of-a-tensor-product-of-two-vector-bundles?rq=1). For direct sum, use the exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal  F \to \mathcal F \oplus \mathcal G \to \mathcal G \to 0.$

Comment: @Krish  Oh... thanks!